# Como alterar o backgroundColor de uma TabNavigator no React-Native

Tags: react-native

```
class TelaInicial extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: 'Trevo',
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            inactiveTintColor: '#eee',
            showIcon: true,
            showLabel: true,
            animationEnabled: false,
            lazyLoad: true,
            upperCaseLabel: false,
        }
    })
```

Fiz esse bloco, mas continua com as cores padrões default.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá utilizar a propriedade `style` dentro do `tabBarOptions` para setar o `backgroundColor` ao seu tabBar, assim como mostra a [documentação do react-navigation.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html)

```
class TelaInicial extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: 'Trevo',
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            inactiveTintColor: '#eee',
            showIcon: true,
            showLabel: true,
            animationEnabled: false,
            lazyLoad: true,
            upperCaseLabel: false,
            style: { //Adição do style
                backgroundColor: '#00ff00', // Aplicando a cor ao background
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Funcionou de primeira!
Muito obrigada! :)

Comment: @AlineLisboa Se funcionou da maneira como necessitava e supriu seu questionamento, favor marcar como correta.